# pagination on multiple txt files

Tags: php, html

I hope you can help me with a problem that I do not know how to solve.

It turns out that I have a database of telephone numbers in a txt file, as this file weighs almost 2GB, I decided to split them into files with about 20,000 lines, generating 5000 txt files in this way.

I would need to include them using an include within a div in the following way

```
<php include "file1.txt"; ?>
```

the problem is that I would have to do this task 5000 times, generating another 4999 php files to include within a div.

It occurs to me then, to do something so that I take all the txt files of a certain directory, the pages and load them into the div when I click on the paginated link.

Try a code that I found as the following

```
<? php $ folder = "arg /";
$ files = scandir ($ folder);

if (isset ($ _ GET ['alpha'])) && strlen ($ _ GET ['alpha']) == 1) {
    foreach ($ files as $ file) {
        $ reg = '/ ^'. $ _GET ['alpha']. '. * \. php $ / i';

        if (preg_match ($ reg, $ file)) {
            echo '<a href="'.$folder.$file.'">'. $ file. ;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

But I do not work the absolute, could you give me a little hand please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should take a look at the formatting on your code and make an edit on the question. The dollar signs got disconnected from their variables. Also, a representative snippet from your text file would be helpful as part of a [mcve]. Thanks.

Comment: I do not know how to add the code correctly, the forum gives me an error and does not let me publish

Comment: Check out https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Comment: I just tried but it does not work out, it's very impractical, to top it all I do not speak English I'm in the google translator

Comment: There might be a Stack Overflow site in your language: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285042/399876